# Get number of rows from SELECT query _before_ any fetch

Tags: cx-oracle

With psycopg2, you have psycopg2.cursor.rowcount that gives you the number of rows that results from your query, before any fetch on the cursor.
It allows you to understand quickly if the cursor returned any result.

On cx_Oracle, cursor.rowcount has a different meaning, it gives you the number of rows that *have been* fetched.

What the Oracle equivalent of psycopg2's rowcount ?
Or have you a method to quickly check if your query returned any datarow ? (Google didn't help me on this point !)

Comment: would be sqlalchemy be of any help ?

Comment: maybe (not checked) but anyway i don't want to be tied with sql-alchemy.